# Calculate scroll gesture value of rotated view

Tags: android, android-animation, coordinate-transformation

I am trying to create a custom `ImageView` with rotation, scaling and scrolling features. I am using `GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener` to get the scroll value.

The rotation and scaling features are working fine and the scroll feature is also working properly until I rotate the `ImageView` at some angle. For example, if I scroll from left to right on `ImageView`, `onScroll` returns some value for `distanceX` and approximately 0 for `distanceY`. But if I rotate the `ImageView` 90 degrees, `onScroll` returns approximately 0 for `distanceX` and some value for `distanceY` for the same gesture.

I have tried to map these "distance" values using a `Matrix` with the following method:

```
private PointF rotate(float distanceX, float distanceY) {
    Matrix transform = new Matrix();
    transform.setRotate(imageView.getRotation());

    float[] pts = new float[2];

    pts[0] = distanceX;
    pts[1] = distanceY;

    transform.mapPoints(pts);

    return new PointF(pts[0], pts[1]);
}
```

But it is not working. So how can I get the scroll value of the rotated view?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this??